# Get the maximum value of second clause

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get the order id maximum by the relative user id

```php
$order_id = "select * from products_orders  where order_user_id = $user_id AND MAX(order_id) ";
$ord_del = mysqli_query($con,$order_id) ;
$ord_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ord_del);
```

i try this method but this wont work

Answer (score -1):

The `MAX` SQL command is a group function which needs to indicate with the common columns. So just adding the `GROUP BY` should work as you want.

```php
$order_id = "SELECT order_user_id,order_id FROM products_orders WHERE order_user_id = $user_id AND MAX(order_id) GROUP BY order_user_id";
```

Comment: Nope, it won't work as they want. It won't work at all

Comment: @Muhammad, please if this answer doesn't work for you then, you need to give more info on the structure of table and maybe some background of the data. I tested and for me and it works as intended assuming that the column `order_id` is an `int auto_increment` type. @yourcommonsense I love critic with reasoning but I hate smack in the face and leave the room without explaining. I doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Just to explain: this site is not about critic. It explicitly says, "SO is not a forum. Only questions and answers." If you have a question you may ask it the usual way. Though I encourage you to do some research first, as the rules suggest.